# To change the default text "No File Selected" of a browser button with some other text in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a file browser button in my jsp. It has a text like "No File Selected" beside it at the very beginning. after selecting the file, it shows the file path instead of "No File Selected". Now I want to replace "No File Selected" with ".jpg" or the supported format names.
Is it possible to do so?

my code for the browser button..

```
 <form:input name="file1" type="file" accept="image/png,image/jpeg"
    id="files" path=""  size="500" title="files" />
```

Comment: Check this link it explains the basis of styling such input, they require more work that other basic inputs. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: sorry could you try clarifying this part //Quote:""Now I want to replace "No File Selected" with ".jpg" or the supported format names. Is it possible to do so?""

Comment: I mean to say that i want to change the default text which is "No File Selected" with some other text , for example "No Items are Selected yet" or some other text. @FelixLahmer

Comment: @user3450546 something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4r928/

Answer (score 0):

Use this style...

in order for you to make a design of you input file..

do not display the input.. just hide it and make a design on your button or whatever element you want. Just like my example below..

```
<input type="file" id="myUpload" style="display:none" />
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('myUpload').click();">Upload Photo</button>
```

I hid the input while displaying the button and giving it an attribute onclick and letting the javascript do the magic..

here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/aYd72/

and better use bootstrap for better designs
I hope it will help you

Comment: No, I want the whole browser button format, as it's default style. Just want to replace the text beside the button. By the way nice trick. Like it . Thank you. :-)

Comment: :) thanks.. and i think i don't have an idea of doing what you want.. and actually i also tried finding the solution of that and i come up with that trick